# Under what conditions $M \cong (M/N) \oplus N$ where $M$ is an $R-$module and $N$ is a submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm curious about it. I know that if $M=A\oplus B$ then  $M/A \cong B$ (identifying $A$ with $A\oplus 0$), one would expect that the "converse" holds, i.e., if $M/A\cong B$ then $M\cong A\oplus B$. Is it true in general? (Assume $R$ is an integral domain).

Comment: No: $ \(mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathb{Z} $ but $mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) \not \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

Comment: @Diego, the quotient $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ has no sense since $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is not even a subset of $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$. Am I wrong?

Comment: But $\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z} $ contains a copy of it. I meant that, I agree with you, it is not quite clear. It's an abuse of notation.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you. Now I ask: Under what conditions can this be true? I tried to understand the "Splitting lemma" Lehs provided but it doesn't help me so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Let $M=R=\mathbb{Z}$, $N=2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I thought that $f: \mathbb{Z}\to (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\oplus 2\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f(n)=(0,n)$ is $n$ is even and $f(n)=(1,n-1)$ if $n$ is odd was an $R-$module isomorphism but I finally found it's not. How do you prove easily that these groups are not isomorphic? That's probably very easy but I cannot see it.

Comment: I think I've got it: $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus 2\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of order two (1,0) while $\mathbb{Z}$ has not.

Comment: @Devilathor Yes, there is no homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z_2}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ok, many thanks. Now I'm asking, under what conditions does it hold?

Comment: @Devilathor  You can use the splitting lemma. Here the exact sequence is $0 \to 2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$. It's not right split.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look to that lemma (I'm just learning about exact sequences). Many thanks!

Comment: A consequence of that $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact, is that $A$ is (isomorphic to) a subset of $B$ and that $C$ is (isomorphic to) $B/Im\alpha$ where $Im\alpha$ is isomorphic to A.